# Neural Network Example Source-code (preferably Python)

Tags: python, neural-network

I wonder if anyone has some example code of a Neural network in python. If someone know of some sort of tutorial with a complete walkthrough that would be awesome, but just example source would be great as well!

Thanks

Comment: Neral network python implementation - https://github.com/AmaldevTA/ML_Basics/blob/master/003_Neural_Networks/Neural_network.ipynb

Answer (score 4):

Found this interresting discusion on ubuntu forums
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=320257

```
import time
import random

# Learning rate:
# Lower  = slower
# Higher = less precise
rate=.2

# Create random weights
inWeight=[random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)]

# Start neuron with no stimuli
inNeuron=[0.0, 0.0]

# Learning table (or gate)
test =[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
test+=[[0.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
test+=[[1.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
test+=[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]

# Calculate response from neural input
def outNeuron(midThresh):
    global inNeuron, inWeight
    s=inNeuron[0]*inWeight[0] + inNeuron[1]*inWeight[1]
    if s>midThresh:
        return 1.0
    else:
        return 0.0

# Display results of test
def display(out, real):
        if out == real:
            print str(out)+" should be "+str(real)+" ***"
        else:
            print str(out)+" should be "+str(real)

while 1:
    # Loop through each lesson in the learning table
    for i in range(len(test)):
        # Stimulate neurons with test input
        inNeuron[0]=test[i][0]
        inNeuron[1]=test[i][1]
        # Adjust weight of neuron #1
        # based on feedback, then display
        out = outNeuron(2)
        inWeight[0]+=rate*(test[i][2]-out)
        display(out, test[i][2])
        # Adjust weight of neuron #2
        # based on feedback, then display
        out = outNeuron(2)
        inWeight[1]+=rate*(test[i][2]-out)
        display(out, test[i][2])
        # Delay
        time.sleep(1)
```

EDIT: there is also a framework named chainer
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chainer/1.0.0

Comment: How does the bias play in this code? I don't quite see it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [**Monte**](http://montepython.sourceforge.net/):

> Monte (python) is a Python framework
>   for building gradient based learning
>   machines, like neural networks,
>   conditional random fields, logistic
>   regression, etc. Monte contains
>   modules (that hold parameters, a
>   cost-function and a gradient-function)
>   and trainers (that can adapt a
>   module's parameters by minimizing its
>   cost-function on training data).
>
> Modules are usually composed of other
>   modules, which can in turn contain
>   other modules, etc. Gradients of
>   decomposable systems like these can be
>   computed with back-propagation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a probabilistic neural network tutorial :http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAKu4g7lBxU

And my Python Implementation:

```
import math

data = {'o' : [(0.2, 0.5), (0.5, 0.7)],
        'x' : [(0.8, 0.8), (0.4, 0.5)],
        'i' : [(0.8, 0.5), (0.6, 0.3), (0.3, 0.2)]}

class Prob_Neural_Network(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def predict(self, new_point, sigma):
        res_dict = {}
        np = new_point
        for k, v in self.data.iteritems():
            res_dict[k] = sum(self.gaussian_func(np[0], np[1], p[0], p[1], sigma) for p in v)
        return max(res_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda k : k[1])

    def gaussian_func(self, x, y, x_0, y_0, sigma):
        return  math.e ** (-1 *((x - x_0) ** 2 + (y - y_0) ** 2) / ((2 * (sigma ** 2))))

prob_nn = Prob_Neural_Network(data)
res = prob_nn.predict((0.2, 0.6), 0.1)
```

Result:

```
>>> res
('o', 0.6132686067117191)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm running this in Python 3 and I have the following error. AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @GabrielaPlantie, change `.iteritems()` to `.items()`; it should fix it.